# Difference between connection, instances, and sessions in SQL

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between Connection, instances, and sessions in the SQL server? I tried to find the differences but one and others are interrelated.

- Connection: It is the number of instances connected to the database.
- Sessions: A session run queries.
- Instance: It is a copy of the sqlservr.exe executable that runs as an operating system.

Any explanation with examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A connection refers to the layer-4 (TCP or Named Pipes or Shared Memory or etc...) connection between a client and the server.

A session is the "logical" unit of a client connection and uniquely identifies a client.  A session can have multiple active commands and is the entity which "holds" locks on an object.  Sessions are normally 1:1 with connections (the exception that comes to mind is the [Context Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/context-connection?view=sql-server-ver15).)

An instance is the SQL Server process running on a server which provides the SQL Interface to the databases.  It frequently listens on TCP ports to accept connections from clients to create new sessions.